# CTP5 EF Code First Question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

You can find the source code demonstrating this issue @ http://code.google.com/p/contactsctp5/

I have three model objects.  Contact,ContactInfo,ContactInfoType.  Where a contact has many contactinfo's and each contactinfo is a contactinfotype.  Fairly simple I guess.  The problem I'm running into is when I go to edit the contact object.  I pulled it from my contact repository.  Then I run "UpdateModel(contact);" and it updates the object with all the values from my form. (monitoring with debug)  When I save the changes though, I get the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship
>   could not be changed because one or
>   more of the foreign-key properties is
>   non-nullable. When a change is made to
>   a relationship, the related
>   foreign-key property is set to a null
>   value. If the foreign-key does not
>   support null values, a new
>   relationship must be defined, the
>   foreign-key property must be assigned
>   another non-null value, or the
>   unrelated object must be deleted.

It seems like after I call update model it nulls out my references and this seems to break everything?  Any thoughts on how to remedy would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here are my models:

```
public partial class Contact {
    public Contact() {
      this.ContactInformation = new HashSet<ContactInformation>();
    }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactInformation> ContactInformation { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class ContactInformation {
    public int ContactInformationId { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int ContactInfoTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Information { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactInfoType ContactInfoType { get; set; }
  }

  public partial class ContactInfoType {
    public ContactInfoType() {
      this.ContactInformation = new HashSet<ContactInformation>();
    }

    public int ContactInfoTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactInformation> ContactInformation { get; set; }
  }
```

My Controller Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Contact person) {
      if (this.ModelState.IsValid) {
        var contact = this.contactRepository.GetById(person.ContactId);
        UpdateModel(contact);
        this.contactRepository.Save();
        TempData["message"] = "Contact Saved.";
        return PartialView("Details", contact);
      } else {
        return PartialView(person);
      }
    }
```

Context Code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .HasMany(c => c.ContactInformation)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContactId);

      modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInfoType>()
        .HasMany(c => c.ContactInformation)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContactInfoTypeId);
    }
```

Comment: Is the error independent of the kind of changes you make on your form? I could imagine that such an error can occur if your delete a `ContactInformation` from the collection in `Contact`. Does the error also happen if you only change for instance the `FirstName` on your form and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this question out thanks to Morteza Manavi on the entity framework website.  My issue was caused by my ContactInformation model properties, 'contactid' & 'contacttypeid' not being nullable.  Once I fixed this everything with UpdateModel() worked correctly.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things going on here.

**1** If you are set up for lazy loading child objects are only loaded if you tell them to load. This can be done with the following in your query.

..

```
context.Contacts.Include(c => c.ContactInfos).Include(c => c.ContactInfos.ContactInfoType)
```

see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) for full details on making sure objects are loaded as you want.

**2** If you don't want to save contactinfo and contactinfotype (because they are not loaded or you just don't want to), you will need to tell the context not to save child objects that shouldn't be updated. This can be done using:

..

```
context.StateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity.ContactInfos.ContactInfoType, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

I find I need to do that when changing/using a country object to user data. I definitely never want that to be updated by a user.

In the middle of writing a bit of a guide to all this, but could be weeks until it's done on my [blog](http://stuartgatenby.com)

**3** MVC won't store/send back anything you don't put into the form. If you send an object heirarchy to the form and the values aren't represented in hidden inputs, they will come back empty on your model. For this reason, I generally make viewmodels that are editable only versions of the entities with a ToEntity and a ToModel method on them. This also covers me for security as I don't want all sorts of user ids in hidden inputs, just so my entities map straight into MVC (see [this article on overposting](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html)).

I WOULD have thought that the fact you have your contactinfo properties set to virtual, the UpdateModel wouldn't mind if they didn't exist on the return, but I could well be wrong as I haven't tried it.

Comment: My contactinfo and contactinfotype properties are marked as virtual.  I get my contact object from the context, by a simple context.Contact.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == id);

Comment: OK, reread my answer and it was a bit skewed edited it now. Have you tried explicitly including? I usually add a default load level in my repository GetQuery methods. It would look like the example in my 1st point. Change yuour  context.Contact.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == id) to  context.Contact.Include(c => c.ContactInfos).SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == id)

Comment: I tried adding the includes, but that didn't change anything and I still get the same error.  All the values in the form are getting correctly mapped to the person variable and everything looks good when you debug.  However, when I preform the updatemodel() it seems to null the references and when I save it fails.

Comment: OK sounds like the issue is with the updatemodel. As you say it's nulling out the references. I'm certainly no expert with UpdateModel as I don't use it much myself. I'm generally creating ViewModels just for editing as my heirarchies get quite complex. You could also try to update the children first? Like UpdateModel(contact.ContactType, "ContactType") if you are actually referencing those objects in your form. Sorry I couldn't fix your problem mate.

Comment: You can find the source code demonstrating this issue @ http://code.google.com/p/contactsctp5/